# Is there any way to catch the response data which is causing the POST 400 (Bad Request) for Vue js fetch api?

Tags: vue.js, fetch-api

I am sending post request from an array by looping through all indexes one by one.

```
function apiService(endpoint, method, data) {
  // D.R.Y. code to make HTTP requests to the REST API backend using fetch
  const config = {
    method: method || "GET",
    body: data !== undefined ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFTOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN
    }
  };
  return fetch(endpoint, config)
           .then(handleResponse)
           .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

```
let len = this.rowObject.length;
for (var i = 0; i <len; i++) {
  apiService(endpoint, method, this.rowObject[i]);                   
}
```

I want to catch the `this.rowObject[i]` object or the `i` index which causes bad 400 request.
Can it be done using try catch?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject an error handler that captures the information you want, like with `onError` below.

```
function apiService(endpoint, method, data, onError) {
  // D.R.Y. code to make HTTP requests to the REST API backend using fetch
  const config = {
    method: method || "GET",
    body: data !== undefined ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFTOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN
    }
  };
  return fetch(endpoint, config)
           .then(handleResponse)
           .catch(onError)
}

let len = this.rowObject.length;
for (var i = 0; i <len; i++) {
  let onError = error => console.log("Error on rowObject " + i + ": " + error);
  apiService(endpoint, method, this.rowObject[i], onError);                   
}
```